# Implement ctrl+x's behaviour same as ctrl+c without use of Flash

Tags: javascript, html, selection

In my web application, I need a shortcut ctrl+x to hate the same behavior as ctrl+c when some text in

paragraph is selected (selection is not in textarea or text input). I need solution without use of Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to prevent the default action on the cut-event. You can do this the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#input').live("cut",function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();

      });
    });
```

Most browsers prevent control of the clipboard. Although I know the following jQuery-plugin exists that gives you a bit of control of it: [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)

**Note:** You must use the Flash add-in you do not want to use to automatically copy text to the client's clipboard. A website automatically modifying the client's clipboard without the aid of active-x components is a security concern.